# Connect iPhone Lightning Headphones to Mac 2014 (standard headphone jack)

Tags: iphone, mac, headphones

I have a Mac 2014 with the standard headphone jack.  My headphones have the Lightning connector.   Ive spent 30 minutes trying to find a converter but no luck so figured I'd try here on Stack. Closest I came was this [Anker Piece](https://www.gearpatrol.com/tech/a583223/lighting-usb-c-dongle-anker-earpods-macbook/) but thats for USB-C (newer mac)

Picture below [image]

Comment: Based on the answer below it may be simpler to just purchase a set of [EarPods that use a 3.5mm plug](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug) - US$20

Comment: Thanks that sounds like it's the easiest.

Comment: If you have more than $20, look at some non-Apple buds. At the top end, the US$300 Bose sound-canceling buds seemed extravagant when I bought them 5 years ago, but they've proved invaluable and have never let me down. The noise-canceling is _that good_. You might want even consider cutting the cord and using Bluetooth earbuds/headphones. Anker makes an excellent Bluetooth US$60 headset, which I use at work for Zoom calls. _Disclaimer: no ties, financial or otherwise, to Bose® or Anker®_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say one does not exist.

The reasoning behind you being able to find an adaptor from USB-C to lightning is that both are digital connections. I'm not sure what, if any, data translation would need to be done, but if it was necessary USB-C can carry the power to do it. (Similarly for the lightning to audio cable supplied with the iPhones).

To do the same from a regular headphone socket would need the adaptor to carry two-way DACs (digital analogues converters) to & from the earphones & mic, & would also have to be battery-powered, as it can't take power from the headphone socket on the Mac.

It's not impossible to do that, but it would be costly. It seems so far, no-one is willing to see if the consumer would be prepared to pay the price.

Comment: Agreed. Even if you went with a USB (audio) adapter there are lots of USB - Lightning adapters but none with a **female** Lightning port on one end and USB-A on the other that I found online